# Kick or Ban user or client in Mosquitto MQTT

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto, broker

i have a configured Mosquitto MQTT broker...

I'd like to **kick** or **ban** a user for an amount of time?

How can i do this from another subscribed client? 
Should i do this from the broker? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't block on a client id basis, the only option would be to enable ACLs with a database back end (something like https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug) and then update the database to remove access to topics to specific users.

Comment: So... a background process to update ACL in Mysql?
Is this plugin capable to filter topics?

Comment: Yes, you can set topic level filters